# Value error in converting a column from object to float

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert a column "value $" from datatype "Object" to "float" as this column would be involved in a numeric computation.

I initially replaced "$" in this column using:

```
 df['Value $'] = df['Value $'].replace({'\$': ''},regex=True)
```

Then convert it into numeric using:

```
 df['Value $'] = df['Value $'].astype(dtype=np.float64)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use this to replace.

```
df['Value $'] = df['Value $'].fillna(0.0).str.replace('[$,]', '').astype('float')
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably it's because you should to replace the commas as well:

```
df['Value $'] = df['Value $'].replace({'\$|,': ''}, regex=True)
df['Value $'] = df['Value $'].astype(dtype=np.float64)
```